# Symfony2 is running extremely slow on php7-fpm on multi docker

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to setup symfony2 environment on multi-docker using php7-fpm and nginx.

The whole thing works. However, for some inexplicable reason, every request takes 20-30 seconds to complete (the whole page loads in about 5 minutes). And during the load, the CPU spikes. I tried playing with php fpm config, nginx config. Even copied the exact ones that I am using for another app, which works perfectly fine. At this point, I am stuck, and I have no idea even where to start (continue).

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
web:
  build: ./
  container_name: indago_web
  external_links:
    - mysql:mysql
  volumes:
    - ./php-fpm/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    - ~/Dev/indago/indago:/var/www/indago
  environment:
    ING_DB_USER: priz_wp
    ING_DB_PASSWORD: Shurik_0(8
    ING_DB_NAME: priz_wp
    ING_DB_HOST: mysql
proxy:
  image: nginx
  container_name: indago_proxy
  links:
    - web:web
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./web/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./web/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Dockerfile of the webapp:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim \
    libxml2-dev libicu-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt-get autoremove

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version

# Set timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Vancouver /etc/localtime
RUN "date"

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql opcache ctype json xml tokenizer mbstring iconv posix intl

RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini


RUN { \
        echo 'upload_max_filesize = 100M'; \
        echo 'post_max_size = 100M'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/cutom.ini


CMD mkdir -p /var/www/indago

VOLUME /var/www/indago

CMD chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/indago

WORKDIR /var/www/indago

#RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
#USER www-data

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And default.conf

```
server {
    server_name indago-local.com www.indago-local.com;
    root /var/www/indago/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass web:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass web:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

In www.conf I updated `pm.max_children = 20`

nginx.conf is pretty simple (and, in fact, does not change anything)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log on;
  error_log on;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
}
```

As some additional information, memmory on fpm container does not swap and I am not getting any errors anywhere (before I bubmped number of children, I was maxing out on them)

Thanks you in advance for any idea about how to resolve it.

Comment: This is not clear for me "And during the load, the CPU spikes." - CPU is iddling with some spikes, or it's fully loaded during processing the request?

Comment: One suggestion in my mind - I had a simmilar problem on a linux server, due to improper configuration of DNS / hosts. It was no Docker server, but may help...

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Almost fully loaded, but if I run `top`, each running fpm process is at ~15% during execution.

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Not sure what do you mean by that

Comment: The server didn't know what is it's hostname and where to resolve DNS. It was causing enormous delay on request. But may not be your problem, just my suggestion.

Comment: To be honest, I am not even sure if the problem in fpm or nginx

Comment: @HonzaRydrych How did you solve that problem that you are talking about?

Comment: I solved it by correcting /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/hosts, but this shouldn't be your problem, because it was causing only timeouts. Your issue is obviously realted to CPU utilization.

Comment: Are you using Docker on OS X or Windows? [Docker is known to have slow disk i/o on these hosts if you have mounted volumes](https://forums.docker.com/t/file-access-in-mounted-volumes-extremely-slow-cpu-bound/8076/188). You can try to delete your containers and relaunch them without any volume (in `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`) especially for the `vendor` and `var` folders, because they are strongly requested on symfony apps.